# How to easly convert linq result to Business Object Collection <T>

Tags: linq, casting, business-objects

I have Business Object Collection

I'd like to filter rows using linq, but noticed it returns IEnumerable  what can not be cast then to my BOC

E.g I cannot do that

```
BOC <Client> bocCLients = (BOC <Client>) 
                          from C in ClientsColl where C.ClientId == 100 select C
```

I've resolved that by looping by linq results and adding returned object to my original collection.

I wonder if there is simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

```
var bocCLients = ClientsColl.Where(c => c.ClientId == 100).ToList();
```

Or

```
var bocCLients = new BOC<Client>(ClientsColl.Where(c => c.ClientId == 100));
```

**Edit**
Or maybe an AddRange extension

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> colSource, IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            if (colSource is List<T>)
                ((List<T>)colSource).AddRange(collection); //If List use build in optimized AddRange function
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in collection)
                    colSource.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for good tips, but #1 creates List <Client>, not BOC<CLient>, #2 requires additional BOC constructor accepting IEnumerabel I think ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a perfect opportunity to create an extension method. From looking at your question, it appears that ClientsColl already contains objects of type Client. In this case, your solution of a foreach loop is ideal. However, you can encapsulate that solution into an extension method and make it reusable and easy to read.

Here's an example of how it would look like:

```
 public static BOC<T> ToBOC<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sourceCollection)
 {
     var boc = new BOC<T>();
     foreach (T item in sourceCollection)
     {
         boc.Add(item);
     }
     return boc;
 }
```

Using this extension method, you would just write your query as follows:

```
BOC<Client> bocClients =
(
    from C in ClientsColl
    where C.ClientID == 100
    select C
).ToBOC();
```

**EDIT**:

To follow up on the idea of the more generic extension method to ICollection, but keeping in line the original question which was to perform a sort of Cast to a specific type of collection, and now having the new information that BOC implements ICollection, here is a more generic extension method and usage to perform the job:

```
public static TCollection ToICollection<T, TCollection>(this IEnumerable<T> sourceCollection)
        where TCollection : ICollection<T>, new()
    {
        TCollection col = new TCollection();
        foreach (T item in sourceCollection)
        {
            col.Add(item);
        }
        return col;
    }
```

And usage:

```
BOC<Client> bocClients2 =
(
    from C in ClientsColl
    where C.ClientID == 100
    select C
).ToICollection<Client, BOC<Client>>();
```

Does this look more useful? Let me know what you think.

Comment: @David Or an Extension method to ICollection<T> called AddRange, that does the above. Will than work on any collection, not only BOC<T>

Comment: That could work also provided that the BOC object implements ICollection<T> (I could not assume that from the provided details of the question). I would not call it AddRange because you are trying to cast to a type and return that type, not add items to an existing collection, right? Also I wrote another extension method which takes a Func<TSource, TResult> in case your ClientsColl would not contain Client objects but some ORM entity, for example.

Comment: With your AddRange extension method, you would need an instance of BOC, so the syntax would be BOC<Client> bocClients = new BOC<Client>().AddRange( ... your linq query in here ...)

Comment: public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> sourceCollection, IEnumerable<T> addItems)
        {
            foreach (T item in addItems)
            {
                sourceCollection.Add(item);
            }
        }

Comment: @David Yep you're right, can't assume  ICollection<T> is implemented, but it should be if it is any type of collection.

Comment: Good idea. ICollection<T> is implemented indeed in BOC

Comment: @Maciej: I just made an edit, not sure if you get notified or not - take a look at the more generic version I added.

Comment: @Maciej: I know that <Client, BOC<Client>> seems repetitive but I could not find a way around it yet, it would be nice to do .ToICollection<BOC<Client>> ... will try to see if that is even possible.